# Getting var value from within a div

Tags: jquery, var

I've tried a few things but can't get anything to work. How do I get the var's value (jQuery) from whatever has been typed into a div? I think `.load()` might need to be used here but I'm not sure how to use it with this.

```
var product_name = '#title';
```

Thanks.

Comment: what you are asking is not clear... what do you want to do with `product_name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var product_name = $('#title').html();
```

here title is id of div

Answer (score 0):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
var product_name = $('selector').html();
```

where selector is any selector you want.